# Getting different results using ggplot and base plot functions

Tags: r, charts, plot, subset

I have a table available here: http://ulozto.cz/xAeP3Ahn/res2-txt. I am trying to make a point plot from that.

I read my table:

```
res2<-read.table("res2.txt", header = TRUE, sep="\t")
```

and create 2 plots.

(1) This is the script for single plot function:

```
plot(res2$V2, res2$dist06, type = "n")
points(subset(res2$V2, year == 2006), subset(res2$dist06, year == 2006), pch = 19, col   = "red", cex = 1)
points(subset(res2$V2, year == 2007), subset(res2$dist06, year == 2007), pch = 19, col = "green", cex = 1)
points(subset(res2$V2, year == 2008), subset(res2$dist06, year == 2008), pch = 19, col = "black", cex = 1)
points(subset(res2$V2, year == 2009), subset(res2$dist06, year == 2009), pch = 19, col = "blue", cex = 1)
points(subset(res2$V2, year == 2011), subset(res2$dist06, year == 2011), pch = 19, col = "yellow", cex = 1)
legend("topright", c("2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2011"),
   col= c("red", "green", "black", "blue", "yellow"),
   pch = c(19,19,19,19,19))
```

(2) and for ggplot2:

```
res2$year<-as.factor(res2$year)  # consider year variable as discrete
ggplot(data=res2, aes(x=V2, y=dist06, color=year)) + geom_point(shape=16, pch=50) +
    xlab("threshold") + ylab("Euclidean distance") + 
    scale_fill_hue(name="year") + # set legend title 
    scale_colour_manual(values=c("red", "green", "black", "blue", "yellow")) +
    theme_bw()
```

Here are my results:

[image: results from simple plot function (1) and froom ggplot2 (2)]

My question is, **why I have a different points position in plots generated differently?** is the problem only in different colors and legend?  so are the "subsets" defined wrong? Why 2006 is marked as red in both but has a different position in graph? the same with 2011 and others? Where am I wrong? Thanks for every recommendations, I am lost here third day.

Here is my resuls from excel, so the plot from ggplot2 (2) has to be right
[image: plot from same data in excel]

Comment: I don't think plot (1) is generated by the code in your question. Try: `subset(res2$V2, year == 2006)`; `numeric(0)`.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but to avoid several `point` calls, one for each year, you may create a colour vector by subsetting your "col" vector with the "year" column: `plot(dist06 ~ V2, data = res2, type = "n")`; `points(dist06 ~ V2, data = res2, col = col[factor(res2$year)])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose this is a side-effect of an incorrect usage of `subset`. The first argument to it should be the whole data frame, like so:

```
subset(res2, year == 2006)$V2
```

or

```
subset(res2, year == 2006, select = V2)
```

(Side note: objects returned by these commands are different, but both will work for your plot)

I'd recommend using a bracket notation:

```
res2$V2[res2$year == 2006]
```

Either way, you'll get a correct plot:

[image]

As you may have noticed, you do not have to copy/paste a lot with `ggplot` approach. Nice!

Comment: Thanks @tonytonov, I would never think of that! I have changed "subset" as you have proposed, and it works, thank again! :)